# loop for value differences between consecutive columns

Tags: r, loops

I have the following dataset: the 10-minute instances are taken from a feed that displays the number of bicycles at a station at a given time.  My goal is to find out the difference in value from one time to the next for each `station_id`

```
> dim(sample)
[1]  6 73
> sample
  station_id 2014-08-18 20:00:00 2014-08-18 20:10:00 2014-08-18 20:20:00
1          1                   1                   0                   0
2          2                  18                  18                  19
3          3                   5                   4                   4
4          4                  21                  20                  20
5          5                   9                  10                   8
6          6                   9                   9                   9
  2014-08-18 20:30:00 2014-08-18 20:40:00 2014-08-18 20:50:00 2014-08-18 21:00:00
1                   2                   1                   1                   0
2                  18                  18                  21                  22
3                   4                   4                   4                   4
4                  21                  22                  25                  23
5                   5                   7                   3                   0
6                   9                   9                   9                   9
  2014-08-18 21:10:00 2014-08-18 21:20:00 2014-08-18 21:30:00 2014-08-18 21:40:00
1                   0                   4                   2                   1
2                  21                  22                  22                  21
3                   4                   6                   3                   3
4                  25                  24                  24                  24
5                   0                   0                   0                   0
6                   9                   9                  10                  10
  2014-08-18 21:50:00 2014-08-18 22:00:00 2014-08-18 22:10:00 2014-08-18 22:20:00
1                   3                   2                   3                   2
2                  21                  22                  18                  16
3                   4                   5                   6                   4
4                  25                  22                  21                  21
5                   4                   0                   0                   3
6                  10                  10                  11                  11
  2014-08-18 22:30:00 2014-08-18 22:40:00 2014-08-18 22:50:00 2014-08-18 23:00:00
1                   2                   3                   8                  11
2                  15                  14                  16                  17
3                   4                   4                   4                   4
4                  23                  21                  20                  20
5                   0                   1                   0                   0
6                  11                  12                  12                  12
  2014-08-18 23:10:00 2014-08-18 23:20:00 2014-08-18 23:30:00 2014-08-18 23:40:00
1                  11                  13                  14                  15
2                  17                  15                  10                   3
3                   5                   5                   5                   4
4                  22                  19                  19                  17
5                   1                   0                   2                   3
6                  12                  12                  12                  12
  2014-08-18 23:50:00 2014-08-19 00:00:00 2014-08-19 00:10:00 2014-08-19 00:20:00
1                  16                  16                  17                  19
2                   2                   2                   2                   1
3                   5                   6                   5                   5
4                  18                  19                  19                  20
5                   3                   0                   2                   6
6                  12                  12                  12                  12
  2014-08-19 00:30:00 2014-08-19 00:40:00 2014-08-19 00:50:00 2014-08-19 01:00:00
1                  20                  21                  22                  23
2                   1                   4                   3                   3
3                   3                   3                   3                   3
4                  20                  19                  20                  19
5                   0                   1                   2                   5
6                  12                  12                  12                  12
  2014-08-19 01:10:00 2014-08-19 01:20:00 2014-08-19 01:30:00 2014-08-19 01:40:00
1                  22                  23                  23                  21
2                   3                   4                   4                   4
3                   4                   4                   4                   4
4                  21                  24                  23                  24
5                   0                   3                   2                   1
6                  12                  12                  12                  12
  2014-08-19 01:50:00 2014-08-19 02:00:00 2014-08-19 02:10:00 2014-08-19 02:20:00
1                  22                  23                  22                  22
2                   3                   1                   1                   1
3                   4                   4                   4                   4
4                  24                  22                  21                  22
5                   0                   1                   2                   2
6                  12                  12                  12                  12
  2014-08-19 02:30:00 2014-08-19 02:40:00 2014-08-19 02:50:00 2014-08-19 03:00:00
1                  20                  22                  22                  22
2                   1                   1                   1                   1
3                   4                   4                   4                   4
4                  22                  24                  24                  23
5                   2                   3                   3                   3
6                  12                  12                  12                  12
  2014-08-19 03:10:00 2014-08-19 03:20:00 2014-08-19 03:30:00 2014-08-19 03:40:00
1                  22                  22                  21                  21
2                   1                   1                   1                   1
3                   4                   4                   4                   4
4                  23                  23                  23                  22
5                   4                   3                   3                   3
6                  12                  12                  12                  12
  2014-08-19 03:50:00 2014-08-19 04:00:00 2014-08-19 04:10:00 2014-08-19 04:20:00
1                  21                  21                  21                  21
2                   1                   1                   1                   1
3                   4                   4                   4                   4
4                  22                  22                  23                  23
5                   2                   3                   3                   3
6                  12                  12                  12                  12
  2014-08-19 04:30:00 2014-08-19 04:40:00 2014-08-19 04:50:00 2014-08-19 05:00:00
1                  21                  21                  21                  21
2                   1                   1                   1                   1
3                   4                   4                   4                   4
4                  23                  23                  23                  23
5                   5                   4                   4                   4
6                  12                  12                  12                  12
  2014-08-19 05:10:00 2014-08-19 05:20:00 2014-08-19 05:30:00 2014-08-19 05:40:00
1                  21                  21                  21                  21
2                   1                   1                   1                   1
3                   4                   4                   4                   4
4                  24                  24                  24                  24
5                   4                   4                   4                   4
6                  12                  12                  12                  12
  2014-08-19 05:50:00 2014-08-19 06:00:00 2014-08-19 06:10:00 2014-08-19 06:20:00
1                  21                  21                  21                  22
2                   1                   1                   1                   1
3                   4                   4                   4                   4
4                  24                  24                  24                  24
5                   4                   4                   4                   3
6                  12                  12                  12                  12
  2014-08-19 06:30:00 2014-08-19 06:40:00 2014-08-19 06:50:00 2014-08-19 07:00:00
1                  22                  22                  22                  22
2                   1                   1                   1                   1
3                   5                   5                   5                   5
4                  24                  24                  24                  24
5                   3                   4                   4                   4
6                  12                  12                  12                  12
  2014-08-19 07:10:00 2014-08-19 07:20:00 2014-08-19 07:30:00 2014-08-19 07:40:00
1                  22                  22                  22                  22
2                   6                   5                   5                   5
3                   5                   5                   5                   5
4                  24                  24                  24                  24
5                   4                   4                   4                   4
6                  12                  12                  12                  12
  2014-08-19 07:50:00
1                  22
2                   5
3                   5
4                  24
5                   4
6                  12
```

The final out put should look something like this (of course,the 
actual number of columns will naturally be 73, but it was too much to put into the example).

```
> reshape2
  station_id 2014-08-18 20:00:00 2014-08-18 20:10:00 2014-08-18 20:20:00
1          1                   1                  -1                   0
2          2                  18                   0                   1
3          3                   5                  -1                   0
4          4                  21                  -1                   0
5          5                   9                   1                  -2
6          6                   9                   0                   0
  2014-08-18 20:30:00 2014-08-18 20:40:00
1                   2                  -1
2                  -1                   0
3                   0                   0
4                   1                   1
5                  -3                   2
6                   0                   0
```

How would one loop over all of the columns in R?

Here is a small sample of the data

```
> dput(sample)
structure(list(station_id = 1:6, `2014-08-18 20:00:00` = c(1L, 
18L, 5L, 21L, 9L, 9L), `2014-08-18 20:10:00` = c(0L, 18L, 4L, 
20L, 10L, 9L), `2014-08-18 20:20:00` = c(0L, 19L, 4L, 20L, 8L, 
9L), `2014-08-18 20:30:00` = c(2L, 18L, 4L, 21L, 5L, 9L), `2014-08-18 20:40:00` = c(1L, 
18L, 4L, 22L, 7L, 9L), `2014-08-18 20:50:00` = c(1L, 21L, 4L, 
25L, 3L, 9L), `2014-08-18 21:00:00` = c(0L, 22L, 4L, 23L, 0L, 
9L)), .Names = c("station_id", "2014-08-18 20:00:00", "2014-08-18 20:10:00", "2014-08-18 20:20:00", "2014-08-18 20:30:00", "2014-08-18 20:40:00", "2014-08-18 20:50:00", "2014-08-18 21:00:00"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please consider reading up on [ask] and how to produce a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Please try to make your example as minimal and easy to import as possible. Furthermore, try to show some of your own attempts in solving this. What have you tried? Why did it not work?

Comment: I have included a sample of the data above

Comment: Thanks! Now, can you also include the desired output based on this input, and your own attempts in solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
t(apply(sample[,-1], 1, diff))
```

Answer (score 2):

Shorter and faster is:

```
> set.seed(100)
> df = data.frame(id = 1:10, replicate(8,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)))
> df
   id X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
1   1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
2   2  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  0
3   3  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1
4   4  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  1
5   5  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  1
6   6  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  1
7   7  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  1
8   8  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1
9   9  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  1
10 10  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0

> cbind(df[,1:2],df[,3:ncol(df)] - df[,2:(ncol(df) - 1)])
   id X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
1   1  0  1  0 -1  0  0  0  0
2   2  0  1  0  0  0 -1  1 -1
3   3  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1  0
4   4  0  0  1  0  0 -1  1  0
5   5  0  1 -1  1  0  0 -1  1
6   6  0  1 -1  1 -1  0  0  1
7   7  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  0  1
8   8  0  0  1  0  0 -1  0  1
9   9  1 -1  1  0 -1  1 -1  1
10 10  0  1 -1  0  0  0  1 -1
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a loop you want, one way is below. I'm sure there are more elegant ways....

```
> set.seed(100)
> df = data.frame(id = 1:10, replicate(8,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)))
> df
   id X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
1   1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
2   2  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  0
3   3  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1
4   4  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  1
5   5  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  1
6   6  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  1
7   7  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  1
8   8  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1
9   9  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  1
10 10  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0
> df1 = df
> for(i in 3:ncol(df1)) df1[,i] = df[,i]-df[,(i-1)]
> df1
   id X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
1   1  0  1  0 -1  0  0  0  0
2   2  0  1  0  0  0 -1  1 -1
3   3  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1  0
4   4  0  0  1  0  0 -1  1  0
5   5  0  1 -1  1  0  0 -1  1
6   6  0  1 -1  1 -1  0  0  1
7   7  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  0  1
8   8  0  0  1  0  0 -1  0  1
9   9  1 -1  1  0 -1  1 -1  1
10 10  0  1 -1  0  0  0  1 -1
```